# Generating unique IDs on the fly

Tags: mysql, sql, uniqueidentifier

I'm use this SQL query to create a new ID that is unique to a column. I think I got the idea from another StackOverlow post a long time ago. But it doesn't work, and I'm not sure why. I'll generate 100-200 ids (adding each to the database as it goes) and I'll sometimes end up with duplicates.

Is there anything obvious that could be off with this query?

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 99999) AS random_num
FROM listings 
WHERE 'random_num' NOT IN (SELECT identifier FROM listings)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: why can't you just use an auto-increment field?

Comment: It's a situation where I don't want the next row to be easily guessable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you intend:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 99999) AS random_num
      FROM listings l
     ) l
WHERE random_num NOT IN (SELECT identifier FROM listings)
LIMIT 1
```

Your code has `'random_num'` which is a string and unlikely to match a numeric identifier.

I do think you should just use `auto_increment`.

Comment: yep, that's the ticket. Simple mistake, but I just couldn't see it

Answer (score 0):

for postgresql you could use the technique from this site: [id-generator-for-postgresql](http://rob.conery.io/2014/05/29/a-better-id-generator-for-postgresql/)